# Elasticsearch query malformed, must start with start_object

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm trying to build a little bit complicated query in Elasticsearch. The query is build built in PHP using ongr/elasticsearch-dsl package. This is how the query looks like:

```
Array
(
[query] => Array
    (
        [function_score] => Array
            (
                [query] => Array
                    (
                        [bool] => Array
                            (
                                [must] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [query_string] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [query] => name_suggest:car
                                                        [fuzziness] => 2
                                                        [analyzer] => autocomplete_analyzer
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [should] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [prefix] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [name] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [value] => term
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [functions] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [filter] => Array
                                    (
                                        [term] => Array
                                            (
                                                [is_category] => 1
                                            )

                                        [weight] => 5
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [score_mode] => sum
                [boost_mode] => sum
            )

    )

)
```

This is the json version of the query:

```
{
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "name_suggest:hrad",
                            "fuzziness": 2,
                            "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "should": [
                    {
                        "prefix": {
                            "name": {
                                "value": "term"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "functions": [
            {
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "is_category": true
                    },
                    "weight": 5
                }
            }
        ],
        "score_mode": "sum",
        "boost_mode": "sum"
    }
},
"min_score": 0.5
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

`query_parsing_exception: [_na] query malformed, must start with start_object`

I'm struggling with this error. Could anybody help me with that? I'm running Elasticsearch 5.

Comment: Can you `json_encode` the above array and post the JSON equivalent of your query, it might be easier to analyze.

Comment: I added the json version of the query.

Comment: The `weight` in your filter goes one level higher, i.e. not inside filter but as a sibling of it.

Comment: Thanks! That was the mistake, I couldn't realize it.